# How to install the ASUS BIOS ROM update?

Tags: bios, asus

I have an ASUS all-in-one-PC model ET2210I.
[This](https://www.asus.com/de/supportonly/et2210iuks/helpdesk_download/) is the download section. There is a BIOS update but it only contains a .rom file and no tool to install it and also no readme.
I looked into the BIOS settings (pressing F2 on boot) but there is no option to install an update.
I also tried the MyASUS app on Windows 10 but it shows no updates.

How to install this file?

Comment: The help guides seem to have some info: https://www.asus.com/de/support/FAQ/1008276

Comment: @Mokubai I tried everything as explained on this page. Way 1: The MyASUS app says there are not updates. Way 2: On the download page of my product there is no flash tool. Way 3: WinFlash says I need to install the ATK package but I already installed it. Another WinFlash version says that this program is only for ASUS notebooks.

Comment: In the English version of the above document it says:  Note: If you have any issue during the BIOS updating, please contact the ASUS Service Center.   ...   I suggest you contact them for assistance.

Comment: Download "Easy Update" to install the rom file, choose windows 7 64bit as OS>>>>>>https://www.asus.com/supportonly/et2210iuks/helpdesk_download/

Comment: About Easy Update software>>>>https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012152/

Comment: @Moab Easy Update says there is not update for this computer.

Answer (score 0):

In BIOS get into Advanced Mode --> Advanced --> ASUS EZ FLASH (any number) Utility then select your file.

Comment: And if the OS drive is using Bitlocker protection, suspend that *before* doing the BIOS update: [Suspend BitLocker protection for non-Microsoft software updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/suspend-bitlocker-protection-non-microsoft-updates).